# Cómo podría quitar la t para poder filtrar 2 reuniones entre 2 fechas en java con hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

me gustaría poder mostrar el listado de reuniones que hay entre 2 fechas con hibernate con jpql en java.
El problema que tengo es que cuando intento llamar al método de reunionesEntre2Fechas sin poner la T en las 2 fechas me da un error,  could not be parsed at index 0, pero cuando ponga la T, si me funciona. Intente parsear la fecha de varias formas, pero no se me ocurre la forma correcta para que no se tenga que poner la T en los parametros.

Me podrías ayudar a ver cómo hacer para quitar la t de estos parámetros
Mis clases son las siguientes.

DTO

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
//import java.util.Date;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "reunion")
public class Reunion implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Column(name = "id_reunion")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private LocalDateTime fecha;
    private String asunto;
    
    
    public Reunion(Reunion r) {
        this.fecha = r.fecha;
        this.asunto = r.asunto;
    }

    public Reunion(LocalDateTime fecha, String asunto) {
        this();
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.asunto = asunto;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(LocalDateTime fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public String getAsunto() {
        return asunto;
    }

    public void setAsunto(String asundo) {
        this.asunto = asundo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Reunion [id=");
        builder.append(this.id);
        builder.append(", fecha=");
//      builder.append(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(this.fecha));
        builder.append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(this.fecha));
        builder.append(", asundo=");
        builder.append(this.asunto);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

interfaz IDao

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface IDao<T> {
    Optional<T> getById(Integer id);

    List<T> getAll();

    void save(T t);

    void update(T t);

    void delete(T t);

}
```

ReunionesDao

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Join;
import javax.persistence.criteria.JoinType;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;



public class ReunionDao extends AbstractDao<Reunion> {
    
    public ReunionDao() {
        setClassEntityManager(Reunion.class);
        
    }
    
    //Metodos especificado para cada dao de cada entidad
    public List<Reunion> reunionesEntre2Fechas(LocalDateTime fechaIni, LocalDateTime fechaFin){
        String sqlQ = "FROM "+ Reunion.class.getName() + " WHERE fecha between ?1 and ?2";
        Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(sqlQ);
//      query.setParameter(1, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(fechaIni));
        query.setParameter(1,  fechaIni);
//      query.setParameter(2,  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(fechaIni));
        query.setParameter(2,  fechaFin);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
    
    
}
```

MAIN

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

import javax.persistence.NoResultException;


public class AppFinal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     ReunionDao reunionDao = new ReunionDao();
     System.out.println(reunionDao.reunionesEntre2Fechas(LocalDateTime.parse("2021-08-31T08:03:00"), LocalDateTime.parse("2021-09-01T00:00:00")));

    }

}
```

Comment: Funciona con la T pero no quieres ponerla, ¿Por qué?.

Comment: Gracias por comentar, es que vera no me gusta mucho el formato yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss (creo que es así).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes definir el patrón de la fecha y usarlo en el método parse:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime parsedDate = LocalDateTime.parse("2021-08-31 08:03:00", formatter);
```

Cuando usas el método `LocalDateTime.parse(String)` se usa el formato por defecto: el [ISO-8601](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: gracias por su respuesta.